Unable to run Netsuite script that is using a define function
The following script won't return the desired alert. Upon using a debugger on Netsuite, it only highlights the line for defining the function. What am I doing wrong here?
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(['N/currentRecord', 'N/ui/message', 'N/ui/dialog'], function(currentRecord, message, dialog) {
    
    function validateLine(context) {
        var rec = currentRecord.get();
        
        if (context.sublistId === 'item') {
            var lineItemChecked = rec.getCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'custcol21' // Your custom checkbox field
            });

            // If the checkbox is checked, show an alert
            if (lineItemChecked === true) {
                dialog.alert({
                    title: 'Bulk Delivery Alert',
                    message: 'Please apply Bulk Delivery for this item.'
                });
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    return {
        validateLine: validateLine
    };
});

The aim is to return a dialog box to alert the user that it is a bulk delivery item, when an item with a bulk item box checked is entered on a line in a quote or sales order.

How are you deploying it? Note for a normal client script (deployed as a client script, attached as custom code on a form or via form.clientScriptModulePath) your context will have a currentRecord property so you don't generally need the N/currentRecord module.

Thank you for your comment. I am deploying it under script deployment applies to sales order. Based on your advice i have removed the N/CurrentRecord however the script still won't return desired dialog alert. The debugger stil highlights the define line yellow even without the current record module?

Check if you can see "validateLine function triggered" in the browser console to ensure the script is running.

No it is not, the console doesn't reference to this script at all

Check the following:

does file name in netsuite have .js appended to the end file name?
is deployed in testing or released status?
is script record and deployment record not inactive?
is the context UI included?

